# Simple Form simple_fields_for only show last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a nested simple form to `edit` a user. The user has a profile he/she can update, and a new record is written to the `profile` table.

`simple_fields_for` shows `all` profile records of a `user` due to the relationship `user 1 to many profile records`. ***However, I would like to only show the newest profile record in the form! How can I accomplish that?***

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :lang %>
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :born %>
    <%= f.input :gender %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %> # the magic needed here
        <%= p.input :postal_code %>
        <%= p.input :core %>
        <%= p.input :daytime %>  
        <%= p.input :style %>
    <% end %>
    <% if @is_new %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :status do |s| %>
        <%= s.input :entered, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: Time.current } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How the new record is written to the profile table on update?

Comment: Ok I think I found the solution

Comment: I mean you are intentionally creating new profile on update or the code is misbehaving. If you are creating intentionally, then how?

Comment: I am editing a user that has a profile record. The edit always writes a new profile record to the db, and up new edit the latest profile record should be shown.

Comment: @Pavan seem my answer below what worked, sorry if the question was not well worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit action:

```
   class user > ApplicationController
      ... 
      def edit
        @profile = @user.profile.order("saved DESC").first
      end
      ...
    end
```

The working form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :lang %>
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :born %>
    <%= f.input :gender %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile, @profile do |p| %> # the magic needed here
        <%= p.input :postal_code %>
        <%= p.input :core %>
        <%= p.input :daytime %>  
        <%= p.input :style %>
    <% end %>
    <% if @is_new %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :status do |s| %>
        <%= s.input :entered, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: Time.current } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Little late, but accepted answer is not 100% accurate. (Would just make this a comment, but no rep.)  I would do this like so:

Assuming you have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles  
  ...
  def latest_profile
    profiles.order(...) # query to get whatever record it is you want
  end
end
```

your simple_fields_for can just be

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :profiles, f.object.latest_profile do |p| %>
```

Note the pluralization of :profiles, and that we don't need to clutter the controller with an additional instance variable because you can access the object in the form.  (Using the singular will work I believe, but you will not get params with a key in the form of :profiles_attributes, meaning even more code to account for unique params.)